# Execute range function (e.g. sum, average, median) based on a condition

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, ms-office

I am trying to do something in Excel that seems easy but I cannot figure out which functions to use. I want to calculate the median value of a range of cells, for which it is true that an adjacent cell contains a specific word.

For instance, take these two columns

```
yes | 1
no  | 4
no  | 5
yes | 3
yes | 2
no  | 9
no  | 6
no  | 8
yes | 1
no  | 5
yes | 3
no  | 5
```

Let's say I want to calculate the median for all no-cases, and the median for all yes cases. It would look like this (if I did it correctly):

```
yes | 2
no  | 5
```

I know that for taking the sum, you can use `COUNTIF`, and I also know that there is an `IF` function, but I do not know how to use it to target adjacent cells to the one you want data from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the array formula:

```
=MEDIAN(IF(A1:A12="yes",B1:B12))
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

*(same for the "no" case)*

[image]

Comment: This is great! Could you explain what an array formula actual means/is in Excel?